# Printing current file name with extension in C++

Tags: c++, file

I am writing a C++ code and I want to print the current filename with its extension. Yes, it's one of the frequently asked questions. One solution is to use argv[0]. It is cool, but it's not giving the extension. Can I have it with the extension?

Comment: Which OS - Windows/ Linux?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::cout << __FILE__`???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can print the full path name using `std::cout << __FILE__`.

If you want to print the file name alone, then you can do:

```
std::string file = __FILE__;
size_t index;
for (index = file.size(); index > 0; index--)
{
    if (file[index - 1] == '\\' || file[index - 1] == '/')
        break;
}
std::cout << file.substr(index);
```

Answer (score 2):

Which platform are you on. Following program

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Name: " << argv[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Works perfectly for me on debian (gcc), windows (msvc and mingw gcc)

```
> a.exe
Name: a.exe
> a
Name: a

$ ./a.out
Name: ./a.out
```

It actually contains command used to start the program.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: And how do you test your program? What steps do you perform in order to execute it?

Comment: I am using sublime text 3 editor and it provides the option to run.

Comment: Here's my code: #include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void fread(){
 freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
 freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
 fread();
 printf("%s\n",argv[0]);
 return 0;
}

Comment: @FerozAhmmed: Can you include that code in your question please?  (Formatted with a blank line before and four spaces at the start of each line).